# Simple math quiz

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, callback, counter

My simple math quiz has error it shows that B variable in not defined. I try to defined it as stringvar but still has error.Where should i define the variable?And is my total is the right way to make it continue to calculate fo last interface which is in result box.Can someone shows example to solve it.

```
import Tkinter 
import tkMessageBox

#easybox1
EasyBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox1.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox1.title("Quesion 1")

Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="answer:").pack()

answr1 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox1)
answr1.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox1, text="State the number of edges in a cube")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

def next1():
    total = 0
    if not answr1.get():
       tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr1.get() == 8 :
       total = total + 1
       EasyBox1.withdraw()
       EasyBox2.deiconify()
    elif answr1.get() != 8:
       total = total
       EasyBox1.withdraw()
       EasyBox2.deiconify()
    return

EasyBox2 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox2.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox2.title("Quesion 2")

Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="answer:").pack()

answr2 = Tkinter.Entry (EasyBox2)
answr2.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="What is the place value of the digit 4 in 76421?")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

LabelName2 = Tkinter.Label (EasyBox2, text="A.Thousands B.Hundreds C.Ones D.Tens")
LabelName2.grid(row=1,column=0)
LabelName2.pack()

def mark():
    total = 0
    if not answr2.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr2.get() == B or b :
        total = total + 1
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()
    elif answr2.get() != B :
        total = total
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()
    return


EasyBox2.withdraw()

total = 0


ResultBox = Tkinter.Tk()
ResultBox.geometry("320x260")
ResultBox.title("Results")

LabelName5 = Tkinter.Label (ResultBox, text="Marks : "+`total`, font=("Impact",20))
LabelName5.grid(row=2,column=0)
ResultBox.withdraw()

Tkinter.Button (EasyBox1, text="Next", command=next1).pack()
Tkinter.Button (EasyBox2, text="result", command=mark).pack()

EasyBox1.mainloop()
```

Comment: @WoLy this is my edited for the question level interface can you correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put quotation marks around `"b"` and `"B"`:

```
def mark():
    total = 0
    if not answr2.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('no answer')
    elif answr2.get() in ["B", "b"]:
        total = total + 1
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()
    else:
        total = total
        EasyBox1.withdraw()
        ResultBox.deiconify()
```

Also, the comparison with `or "b"` won't work right now, you could change it to

```
if answr2.get() in ["B", "b"]:
```

or

```
if answr2.get().upper() == "B":
```

Comment: thnx but how to print out the mark if both question get right?Even my answer is correct it show o mark

Comment: There are several issues with the code, including a global `total` variable and also that the ResultBox is generated at startup, when `total` is always zero. Have a look at this Gist: [code](https://gist.github.com/akleemans/08bf25b1558481d1ce6d)

Comment: is there any other way? actually in result box i wanted to convert into percentage score. It is impossible to make the total variable into percentage if the variable define as global. I appreciate the code you have done.

Answer (score 3):

if you want compare the answer with string 'B' or 'b', just quote them